# Div over Google map

Tags: google-maps, html

I have a full page google map that i want to be able to put some images overlayed on the map. so far i have the following code:

```
<style type="text/css"> 
    html { height: 100% } 
    body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 } 
    #map_canvas { height: 100% } 
    #wrapper { position: relative; }
    #over_map { position: absolute; background-color: transparent; top: 10px; left: 10px; z-index: 99; }
    #over_map_right { position: absolute; background-color: transparent; top: 10px; right: 10px; z-index: 99; }

</style>

....

<body>  

<div id="wrapper">

    <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%"></div>

    <div id="over_map">Left hand stuff goes here</div>

    <div id="over_map_right">right hand stuff goes here</div>
</div> 
</body>
```

This code seems right to me, but when open it, i get a plain white screen with just

```
<div id="over_map">Left hand stuff goes here</div>

<div id="over_map_right">right hand stuff goes here</div>
```

displayed.

is there another way to do this? Could it be done with iframes or something like that?

mike

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that google maps need a concrete `height` attribute in order to work.

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/9qDhX/

Note that `height: 400px;` will work, but `height: 100%;` will leave you with a blank screen.

There are various workarounds to get a "full screen" map.  The best, cross-browser ones will use some kind of jQuery to set the height of the `map_canvas` based on the current window size, with a listener to window resize to reset the height.

Answer (score 2):

in addition to Jeff-Meadows answer.

To get the full screen map:

you can use jquery onload event

```
    $(function () {
        $("#map_canvas").css("height", $(window).height());
    });
```

This will enable full screen

Answer (score 0):

You can use `vh` CSS units in your stylesheets.

For example:

```
#map_canvas {
    height: 100vh;
}
```